# Array attribute not parsing to angularjs Directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arrays, angularjs-directive

My directive is

```
angular.module('app').directive('authorDirective',authorDirective);
function authorDirective()
{
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
            Authors: '=',
            details: '&',
            name : '='
        },
        replace : true,
        template: 
        '<table class="table"><thead>'+
        '<tr><th>Name</th><th>Nationality</th><th>Dates</th></tr></thead>'+
        '<tbody ng-repeat="model in Authors">'+
        '<tr><td>{{model.Name}}</td><td>{{model.Nationality}}</td><td>{{model.Dates}}</td></tr>'+
        '</tbody></table>'
    };

}
```

Controller is

```
    angular.module('app').controller('LabController',LabController);
function LabController ()
{
    var vm = this;
    vm.Authors = [
        {Name : "Mark Twain",Nationality : "American", Dates : "1885-1910"},
        {Name : "A.A Miline",Nationality : "English", Dates : "1882-1956"},
        {Name : "Charles Dickens",Nationality : "English", Dates : "1812-1870"},
        {Name : "Jane Austen",Nationality : "English", Dates : "1775-1817"}
    ];
}
```

and the HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app">

<head>
    <title>Directives</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7"
        crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body ng-controller="LabController as vm">
    <div class="container">
        <h1>Directives</h1>
        <author-directive Authors="vm.Authors"></author-directive>
    </div>


    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.5/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="./app/app.js"></script>
    <script src="./app/LabController.js"></script>
    <script src="./app/authorDirective.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

I tried to pass object via scope attribute to directive. It was working. But when I try to pass array I can't. Didn't find any error in browser console also. What Wrong did I make here? Thanks in advance for helping.

[Plunker is here](https://plnkr.co/edit/SLktdKozBQv2SVQye4De?p=preview)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Directive attributes should be low-cased: `authors="vm.Authors"`

<kbd>[Plunker Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/d2V6aCTyWnzpDfCCexmq?p=preview)</kbd>

---

[AngularJS Directive DOCS](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive)

> Normalization
>   AngularJS normalizes an element's tag and attribute name to determine which elements match which directives. We typically refer to directives by their case-sensitive camelCase normalized name (e.g. ngModel). However, since HTML is case-insensitive, we refer to directives in the **DOM by lower-case forms**, typically using dash-delimited attributes on DOM elements (e.g. ng-model).

---

If you want to use `Authors`, you can write `Authors: '=authors',` and in DOM: `<author-directive authors="vm.Authors"></author-directive>`

[Your Fixed Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/gEOYwuSFkXDzsLdewXny?p=preview)

Comment: Thank you man. Got your answer and understood explanation properly and it fixed my problem like a charm.